# Sigabrt error on custom push segue

Tags: ios, objective-c, segue

I received the error: `Thread 1, Signal SIGABRT` when I ran my app and pressed the button when I had added a custom push segue for.

Error in log:

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Pushing a navigation controller is not supported'
```

Here's the code for the custom segue

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface PushNoAnimationSegue : UIStoryboardSegue

@end
```

```
 @implementation PushNoAnimationSegue

    -(void) perform{
        [[[self sourceViewController] navigationController] pushViewController:[self   destinationViewController] animated:NO];
    }

    @end
```

All outlets are accounted for and there don't seem to be any loose ones.

**What's the issue and how do I fix this?**

Comment: For those who are fighting to figure out error in iOS 10, when using library/photos/media your app may be crashing with SIGABORT. You need to add some keys in Info.plist, check [this link.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39631642/1223728)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That error indicates that you are trying to push a `UINavigationController` instance onto a `UINavigationController`.  This is not allowed (as the error states).  It seems like your storyboard is most likely not setup correctly.  You can verify this by checking the type of `[self destinationViewController]`, it should not be a `UINavigationController`.