# iOS 10.2 Simulator do not ask for Photos, Contact permission not even add the app in Settings but works for device .

Tags: ios, permissions, simulator

iOS 10.2 Simulator do not ask for Photos, Contact  permission not even add the app in Settings but works for device . only works for Notifications permissions . I reset simulator but did not work

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39631256/request-permission-for-camera-and-library-in-ios-10-info-plist

Comment: Thanks for reply!
I think that is Simulator bug, because it works fine in device. It shows blank screen in simulator.