# Following iOS Tutorial - Cannot get image picker to display

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

So I'm new to iOS Development and I'm finally onto this step: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/DevelopiOSAppsSwift/WorkWithViewControllers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40015214-CH6-SW1

I've followed the guide step-by-step and for some reason, when I run my app, I click on the Image View and nothing pops up. My code is exactly like Apple's with the exception of `nameTextField` being `businessNameTextField` and `businessNameLabel`. Here's my `ViewController.swift` file

```
//
//  ViewController.swift
//  Example (Sample 1)
//
//  Created by lewlsaucengravy on 4/9/17.
//  Copyright © 2017 Example. All rights reserved.
//

import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate {
    //MARK: Properties

    @IBOutlet weak var businessNameLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var businessTextField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var photoImageView: UIImageView!
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        businessTextField.delegate = self
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
    
    //MARK: UITextFieldDelegate
    
    func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
        // Hide the keyboard.
        textField.resignFirstResponder()
        return true
    }
    
    func textFieldDidEndEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
        businessNameLabel.text = textField.text
    }
    
    //MARK: UIImagePickerControllerDelegate
    func imagePickerControllerDidCancel(_ picker: UIImagePickerController) {
        // Dismiss the picker if user cancelled.
        dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
    
    func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {
        // The info dictionary may contain multiple representations of the image. You want to use the original.
        guard let selectedImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage else {
            fatalError("Expected a dictionary containing an image, but was provided the following: \(info)")
        }
        
        // Set photoImageView to display the selected image.
        photoImageView.image = selectedImage
        
        // Dismiss the picker.
        dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
    
    //MARK: Actions
    @IBAction func completeProfile(_ sender: UIButton) {
        businessNameLabel.text = "test"
    }
    
    @IBAction func selectImageFromPhotoLibrary(_ sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
            // Hide the keyboard.
            businessTextField.resignFirstResponder()
            
            // UIImagePickerController is a view controller that lets a user pick media from their photo library.
            let imagePickerController = UIImagePickerController()
            
            // Only allow photos to be picked, not taken.
            imagePickerController.sourceType = .photoLibrary
            
            // Make sure ViewController is notified when the user picks an image.
            imagePickerController.delegate = self
            present(imagePickerController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

}
```

My `AppDelegate.swift` file is is the default when creating the project, so nothing to show there.

Here's the `Main.storyboard`:

[image: Sample iOS App]

I'm trying to avoid just deleting the app and starting over because I want to get in the habit of troubleshooting and learning what I'm doing wrong.

From what I understand, and feel free to correct me if I'm wrong, when the user clicks on the Image View, it's calling the `selectImageFromPhotoLibrary` function from which I've defined under Actions, and everything is supposed to go from there.

### Edit

It looks like the issue may have been the "User Interaction Enabled" checkbox that I forgot to check. It's the only thing I changed since posting the question and apparently it's working now.

Comment: First thing to check: Did you assign a Tap Gesture Recognizer to your `UIImageView`? And did you connect that to `@IBAction func selectImageFromPhotoLibrary()`? Easiest way to check is to put a breakpoint at `businessTextField.resignFirstResponder()` If you tap the image and *do not* reach the breakpoint, that's what you need to fix.

Comment: That's weird. So the breakpoint wasn't hit. However, assigning the tap gesture recognizer to the image library is just drag from the object viewer over to the actual image view right?

Comment: Check that your image view has User Interaction enabled?

Comment: Someone just mentioned that as an answer and I, in fact, did not have it enabled. However, I enabled it and restarted the app simulation and nothing popped up still.

Comment: In Interface Builder, right-click on your image view... In the popup, see if it *is* connected to the Tap Gesture

Comment: Looks like it is. Under "Outlet Connections" there's "gestureRecognizers" on the left and then "Tap Gesture Recognizer" on the right.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/141286/discussion-between-donmag-and-lewlsauce).

Answer (score 1):

Ensure the User Interaction Enabled checkbox is checked:

[image]

Comment: I forgot to enable this checkbox. I enabled it, but I still wasn't able to click on the image or hit the breakpoint that I set at `businessTextField.resignFirstResponder()`

Answer (score 0):

From what I am thinking, you did not have set the following parameters in your plist:

[image]

Comment: I don't see this in my Info.plist file. Is there another area I'm supposed to be able to see this?

Comment: I think this is your issue :) check out this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/39631642/7715250

Comment: @J.Doe - according to the person asking the question, the code related to the image picker is not even being reached - so it cannot be related to the plist entries.