# Button text not updating from its own action using @state

Tags: swift, swiftui

I am slightly confused with how to properly updating a view button color based on the state. If I am not mistaken, `self.cameraOK` is `true` when the user gives the camera access, but the button color does not change. I need to tap on the button again to see the color change. Why is this behaviour happening?

Also any other recommendations for good standards are encouraged as I am fairly new to swift.

Here is the code:

```
    @State var cameraOK: Bool = false
    @State var photosOK: Bool = false
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack(alignment: .leading) {
            ...
            Button(action: {
                if permissions.giveCameraAccess() {
                    self.cameraOK = true
                }
            })  {
                Text("Enable access to your camera")
                    .font(Font.custom("Inter", size: 16))
                    .foregroundColor(self.cameraOK ? Color(red: 0, green: 1, blue: 0.2) : Color(red: 1, green: 0.68, blue: 0.2) )
                    .fontWeight(.regular)
```

Comment: I think *when the user gives the camera access* assumption is incorrect and you just don't get to assignment. Set breakpoint at that line and you see when do you get there.

Comment: You were right -  the permissions popup is showing, but is jumping to the next instruction before waiting for the popup to get a reply

Comment: For those interested in how to defer asking permission: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39631256/request-permission-for-camera-and-library-in-ios-10-info-plist

Comment: Show more code: what do you do in `permissions.giveCameraAccess()`?